# Dynamic Textures

Tags: unity, textures, javascript

I am pretty new to this 3D designing and animating, and as an indie developer I need to do everything on my own

I have created this simple box character And I want to texture it, have looked around for solution and all seem to require UV-Mapping.
Is it normal if I create a texture for each part of the character (legs have texture,head another texture file and it goes..) Or I should learn it the hard way and simply create one texture for the entire character.

What are the pros and cons of this approach, noting that I am targeting mobiles.
and may I get resources about texturing for mobile games ?

EDIT : knowing that I am targeting mobiles (low resources compared to PC), Is it possible to dynamically render textures via the engine without needing files ? I guess it would be easier to update textures later compared to using a file, knowing the characters are simple cubes and shapes and simple colours would be rendered on them (with few details of course)

Answer (score 1):

Separate textures is very bad performance-wise. Modern content pipelines usually subdivide a mesh in individual parts separated by material, so this adds additional GPU instructions when drawing the model. Here is how drawing a model that has three separate textures five times would be in code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    SetTexture(headTexture);
    SetModel(headModel);
    Draw();

    SetTexture(torsoTexture);
    SetModel(torsoModel);
    Draw();

    SetTexture(legsTexture);
    SetModel(legsModel);
    Draw();
}
```

That would be 15 `SetTexture`, `SetModel` and `Draw` calls each. Knowing that each one has some kind of overhead when calling (mainly due to CPU <-> GPU communication), you end wasting some precious resources and making the frame drawing slower.

Now, this would be the code if you had to draw a model with only one texture:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    SetTexture(bodyTexture);
    SetModel(bodyModel);
    Draw();
}
```

That would equal to 5 `SetTexture`, `SetModel` and `Draw` calls each. But wait, modern engines cache values before performing operations, so when `SetTexture` or `SetModel` are  called with the same value as the last time, no operation is performed because the GPU already has that state set! So in the end, you would have one `SetTexture` and `SetModel` calls, and 5 `Draw`. 7 function calls instead of the 45 you would have the other way.

Comment: any resources on how to create textures for full body and implementing them ?

Answer (score 0):

To use one single texture on a character:

Pro:

- Less textures to store, load, and render. Generally speaking, it's more efficient in time and space.

Con:

- You might have less details on smaller parts.
- If you want to change partial outlook on a character in the game (for example, a paper doll system, or player customized character), you will need a lot more big textures. In this case it's actually taking more spaces in storage, and maybe memory.

So it really depends on your game design.